# A trick for specifying a lower and upper bound in an optimization problem

Tags: algorithm, matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I am minimizing (using the `paretosearch` function in MATLAB) two objective functions that both depend on `x` and `y`.

Suppose we have the constraints `0<= x <=0.5` and `0.1<= y <= 0.3`. In this case we can simply define the lower-bound (`lb`) and upper-bound (`ub`) for a specific optimization problem as follows:

```
lb = [0, 0.1];
ub = [0.5, 0.3];
```

**Instead, suppose now that we have `0.04<= x <=0.5` and `0<= y <=x - 0.03`**:

In this case, we have `lb = [0.04, 0]`, but what about `ub` ?

I think as the minimum value of `x` is `0.04`, so we can only accept `0<= y <= 0.01` and we can reject all other possibilities for `y`. But I believe I am very wrong. So how can I define (in MATLAB) a `ub` that updates automatically with every value of `x`?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: What Matlab function are you using for optimization?

Comment: Upper bounds are constants. So the condition `y <= x - 0.03` has to be specified as a constraint. From the upper bound on x, you can conclude: 0 <= y <= 0.47 (most LP solvers have good pre-solvers which will make this deduction for you automatically)  Note that there is something called VUB -- variable upper bounds. I don't think that plays any role here.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I am using 'paretosearch' function in MATLAB. So in fact I have two objective functions that I want to minimize (a multi-objective optimization problem) but I didn't include that in my question.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thank you for the information. Can you please explain in detail how did you get 0 <= y <= 0.47 ?

Comment: `x <= 0.5, y <= x-0.03 ==> y <= 0.5 - 0.03`

Comment: Because `x <= 0.5`.

Comment: Besides `y <= 0.47` you still need the constraint `y <= x - 0.03`.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen I am still trying it on MATLAB. I have considered the two constraints in David's answer. Do you think I still need to define the lower and upper bound for y? For example  consider the constraints −y ≤ 0, −x + y ≤ − 0.03, and also define that 0 <= y <= 0.47 ? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you should add the constraint and preferably add the bound.

Comment: Because if I don't take the bounds for y, I am obtaining different results than if I take them. I think I should obtain the same results no? btw I will consider them.

Comment: I don't think you can drop `y>=0`.

Answer (score 1):

paretosearch has a form [paretosearch(fun,nvars,A,b)](https://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/paretosearch.html) that lets you specify linear inequalities `Ax ≤ b` in matrix form. Rewrite the constraint `0 ≤ y ≤ x − 0.03` as two: `−y ≤ 0` and `−x + y ≤ − 0.03` and then derive `A = [0,-1;-1,1]` and `b = [0,-0.03]`.

Comment: Ah ok I see. I will apply it in MATLAB and keep you updated. Thank you a lot.

Comment: So in that case, I can define: lb = 0.04; ub = 0.5; A = [0, -1; -1, 1]; b = [0, -0.03]; 
Then: I can write:
opts_ps.ParetoSetSize = 100;  
paretosearch(my_multiObjective_function, 2, [], [], [0,-1;-1,1], [0,-0.03], lb,ub,[], opts_ps); 
Am I right?

Comment: @Christina not a Matlab expert, but I think so.